# React useReducer + useContext can't get value from mapped inputs

Tags: react-hooks

I'm stuck for 3 days trying to get an input value from mapped inputs. I still can't find a solution. I have a group of inputs and I want to add another input when clicked. When I add another input I can't write the code correctly in useReducer to get the value from the added input.

```
import { createContext, useContext, useReducer } from "react";

const QuoteContext = createContext();

const initialState = {
  fields: [{
    units: ""
  }]
};

function reducer(state, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "add":
      {
        return {
          ...state,
          fields: [
            ...state.fields,

            {
              fields: action.field,
            },
          ],
        };
      }

    case "change":
      {
        return [...state, [action.units]];
      }

    default:
      throw new Error("Unknown action type");
  }
}

function QuoteProvider({
  children
}) {
  const [inputField, setInputField] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);
  console.log(inputField);

  const handleAddField = () => {
    const newField = {
      units: "",
    };

    setInputField({
      type: "add",
      field: newField,
    });
  };

  const handleUpdateField = (e, i) => {
    const field = [...initialState];
    field[i] = e.target.value;

    setInputField({
      type: "change",
      units: field,
    });
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

Each input field should have a unique identifier (`name`) by which you update it. Instead of using an array for `fields`, use an object in the form of:

```
{ [name]: field }
```

To generate the `name` you can track the current number of items, or just generate a uuid (I've using [`crypto.randomUUID()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Crypto/randomUUID)).

You can iterate the `fields` object using `Object.entries()` to get an array of `[name, field]` that you can map to render your items.

On each input you should add the `name` property, so that the change handler would known which field to update.

**Example**:

```js
const { createContext, useContext, useReducer } = React;

const QuoteContext = createContext({});

const useQuoteContext = () => useContext(QuoteContext);

const initialState = {
  fields: {}
};

function reducer(state, { type, name, payload }) {
  switch (type) {
    case "add":
      return {
        ...state,
        fields: {
          ...state.fields,
          [name]: payload,
        },
      };

    case "change":
      return {
        ...state,
        fields: {
          ...state.fields,
          [name]: {
            ...state.fields[name],
            units: payload
          }
        }
      };
      
    default:
      throw new Error("Unknown action type");
  }
}

const QuoteProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [inputFields, setInputFields] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);

  const handleAddField = () => {
    const payload = {
      units: "",
    };

    setInputFields({
      type: "add",
      name: crypto.randomUUID(),
      payload,
    });
  };

  const handleUpdateField = e => {
    const { value, name } = e.target;

    setInputFields({
      type: "change",
      name,
      payload: value,
    });
  };
  
  return (
    <QuoteContext.Provider value={{
        inputFields, 
        handleAddField, 
        handleUpdateField 
      }}>
      { children }
    </QuoteContext.Provider>
  );
};

const InputsManager = () => {
  const { inputFields, handleAddField, handleUpdateField } = useQuoteContext();
  
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={handleAddField}>Add Field</button>
      <ul>
      {Object.entries(inputFields.fields)
        .map(([name, field]) => (
          <li key={name}>
            <input
              onChange={handleUpdateField}
              name={name} 
              value={field.units} 
              />
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}

const Demo = () => (
  <QuoteProvider>
    <InputsManager />
  </QuoteProvider>
);

ReactDOM
  .createRoot(root)
  .render(<Demo />);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your solution. Working great with one input. My goal is to have the input group already displayed in the initial rendering. And with the add button, I'll create another groups of inputs. I am trying find solution with your useReducers's logic.

Comment: Just add a field to the initial state, s you'll start with a single input.